LiDAR simulation in O3DE (ROS2)
I'm using O3DE 23.10.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. I've built O3DE from github with the Source engine build type and the Profile build configuration. I've also built the O3DE-extras from source and created a project with the ROS2 gem.
By adding a mesh with a PhysX Primitive Controller Component and a ROS2 Lidar Sensor Component, I am able to simulate LiDAR interaction with the mesh. However, for some reason the point cloud created always stops at the half way mark of the mesh in Z dimension. It doesn't matter where I position or rotate the LiDAR or how big I scale the mesh. The points always only get created up to Z / 2 of the mesh.
In the Y and Z direction the point cloud is created up to the max distance of the LiDAR unit. The same data gets published in the ROS2 topic and hence it shows the same in rviz2.
Anyone any idea what is happening?

vs.

